# NSString to NSUInteger

Tags: cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, nsstring, nsuinteger

I've got a number in a NSString `@"15"`. I want to convert this to NSUInteger, but I don't know how to do that...

Comment: To request support for reading unsigned values from NSString, please visit http://bugreport.apple.com and file a dupe of radar://2264733 against component `Foundation | X`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
NSString *str = @"15";
// Extract an integer number, returns 0 if there's no valid number at the start of the string.
NSInteger i = [str integerValue];
```

If you really want an NSUInteger, just cast it, but you may want to test the value beforehand.

Comment: A little incomplete. This won't work if the value is larger than INT_MAX. And if this is quite likely if you are using it for things like byte lengths.

Comment: Casting it to an NSUInteger (as mentioned) would look like `NSUInteger i = (NSUInteger)[str integerValue];`

Comment: This won't work for many large numbers. For this string, for example: @18140419601393549482" you will get: 9223372036854775807 which isn't what you want. For me, neither intValue, integerValue or even longLongValue gives the right answer.

Answer (score 21):

The currently chosen answer is incorrect for NSUInteger. As Corey Floyd points out a comment on the selected answer this won't work if the value is larger than INT_MAX. A better way of doing this is to use NSNumber and then using one of the methods on NSNumber to retrieve the type you're interested in, e.g.:

```
NSString *str = @"15"; // Or whatever value you want
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong: str.longLongValue];
NSUInteger value = number.unsignedIntegerValue;
```

Comment: Please be more descriptive in your comment hasan83. What exactly did you do that didn't work?

Comment: a value that fits in nsuinteger but not in nsinteger did get converted.

Answer (score 9):

All these answers are wrong on a 64-bit system.

```
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:@"15"];
unsigned long long ull;
if (![scanner scanUnsignedLongLong:&ull]) {
  ull = 0;  // Or handle failure some other way
}
return (NSUInteger)ull;  // This happens to work because NSUInteger is the same as unsigned long long at the moment.
```

Test with 9223372036854775808, which won't fit in a signed `long long`.

Comment: Thank you, this is the only solution that worked with my (rather large) MD5 number - @18140419601393549482"  BTW is there an "NSScanner"-like object that will work on raw data in a C-buffer? NSScanner seems only to work on NSString objects. I'd like to save one conversion...

Answer (score 0):

you can try with `[string longLongValue]` or `[string intValue]`..